# I can't drag and drop messages in Outlook 2003 anymore

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook-2003

I'm 4 days in at my new job and Outlook is already acting up.
I can still right click and go "move to..." but that is a pain compared to dragging and dropping my messages.
How can I reenable dragging and dropping messages in Outlook again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oi, the answer to this one is the oldest in the book. Reboot the computer. :(